# Display the text file containing matching key word asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, full-text-search

Visual Studio, ASP.NET:

-attempting to display a text file which contains the key word specified by the user in search field.

The .txt files are in the same directory as the Default.aspx (nested in project)

current form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- Search field and search button to find desired match -->
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="searchField_id" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="searchButton_id" runat="server" OnClick="Search_Click" Text="Search" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <!-- Text box displaying .txt document information -->
    <div>    
        <asp:TextBox ID="docDisplay_id" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>    
    </div>
 </form>
```

only method besides Page_Load; not a lot of experience with c#

```
 protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IO in asp.net is NOT the way to go, you should use a database for all the data. However here is the code for reading from file.

```
docDisplay_id.Text = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("test.txt"));
```

Comment: Noted, I will look into implementing a database. Thanks for the feedback and code.